# How to develop live chat using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, socket.io-1.0, socket.io-redis

I want to develop live chat using node js. Can anyone guide me how to do this? The use cases I decided :

1. User will see a link or icon on the app screen labeled ‘Online chat support’.
2. Clicking on this, chat window will open up. Either it will indicate the name of an agent who is online and ready, or it will indicate that agents are busy, and change that status once an agent is available.
3. On the agent’s side, upto 3 windows (from 3 users) will be opened up before the busy message is generated for further users. This number (3) will be configurable.
4. The agent will get the name of the screen the user is pinging him from.
5. Since there will be multiple agents, we need ability to tag a bunch of screens (or apps) to a particular agent.
6. A load distribution mechanism is required whereby a new query gets routed to any agent who is free, and tagged to that screen or app.
7. "We need ability to set up an unavailable message for certain time windows – 
   if chat support is only available say between 9 Am and 6 PM IST, we should be able to set up a message for users who log in outside this window that says ‘Online chat support is only available between….”"

Please advise how to proceed.

Comment: This might help you with a basic idea https://github.com/sayar/NodeMVA/tree/master/09_NodeChatroom

Answer (score 2):

You can use `socket.io` module for creating live chat.
Check [this tutorial](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/).

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I know socket.io could be used but not sure how to do it with multiple agents. when user clicks on 'Online chat support’ button, how it would be connected to the available agent? Should the multiple agents will be in one server or multiple server, or cluster needs to be used.